# Problem printing to a shared printer between ubuntu 11.10 machines on home network

Tags: printing

I have a desktop and laptop computer both running ubuntu 11.10.
The desktop has a HP F4100 printer connected via USB. I have shared this printer and selected "Publish shared printers connected to the system" in the printers network menu.

On the laptop I've selected "show printers shared by other system". The shared F4100 printer shows up on the laptop's printer list.

Everything seems like it should be working on both machines. I can see the shared printer in my laptop's printers list. However, when I select the printer for printing, or try to view it's properties the printing system hangs...like it is stuck trying to communicate with the printer...

I'm not sure how to fix this, even when I run the "Problems?" troubleshooter in Ubuntu the system hangs....

Anyone have any ideas about how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

OP answered the question

> Turns out that my firewall was blocking the printer connection from the laptop - opening port 631 solved the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry no real answer other than adding your experience to this bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/883585

Comment: Turns out that my firewall was blocking the printer connection from the laptop - opening port 631 solved the problem...